# Python pandas: multiple columns to multiple rows efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I convert multiple columns of a pandas df to multiple rows like below?
I would like to do this for a very large df, so I'm looking for a relatively fast method.

```
   current df:

          LOG_TIME  QP_HCP  IP_HCP  QP_PRP  IP_PRP
   0      68444.0      4.9     0.6     4.8     3.8


   df I want to obtain:

          LOG_TIME  ORIENTATION    QP    IP
   0      68444.0           HCP   4.9   0.6
   1      68444.0           PRP   4.8   3.8
```

Comment: show us what you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, reshape your DataFrame so you have the following format.

```
    LOG_TIME    ORIENTATION value   result
0   68444.0     PRP         4.8     QP
1   68444.0     HCP         4.9     QP
2   68444.0     PRP         3.8     IP
3   68444.0     HCP         0.6     IP
```

You can do this with the following.

```
new = df.melt(id_vars='LOG_TIME', value_vars=['QP_PRP', 'QP_HCP', 'IP_PRP', 'IP_HCP'], var_name='ORIENTATION')
new[['result', 'ORIENTATION']] = new['ORIENTATION'].str.split('_', expand=True).rename(columns={0: 'result', 1: 'ORIENTATION'})
```

Then you can pivot the data.

```
new = new.pivot_table(index=['LOG_TIME', 'ORIENTATION'], columns='result', values='value')
pd.DataFrame(new.to_records())

Out[6]:

    LOG_TIME    ORIENTATION  IP     QP
0   68444.0     HCP          0.6    4.9
1   68444.0     PRP          3.8    4.8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hcp_df = df[['LOG_TIME', 'QP_HCP', 'IP_HCP' ]].values
prp_df = df[['LOG_TIME', 'QP_PRP', 'IP_PRP']].values
df2 = pd.DataFrame(prp_df, columns=['LOG_TIME', 'QP', 'IP'], index=['PRP'] *prp_df.shape[0])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(hcp_df, columns=['LOG_TIME', 'QP', 'IP'], index=['HCP'] * hcp_df.shape[0])
df1.append(df2).reset_index().rename({'index': 'ORIENTATION'}, axis=1)
```

The following code worked on my side:
here is what I did :

1. get hcp and PRP values from the data frame:
2. create the dataframe with index from IP and QP
3. append the 2 dataframes :

And  the desired output is here :

```
    ORIENTATION LOG_TIME    QP  IP
0   HCP          68444.0    4.9 0.6
1   PRP          68444.0    4.8 3.8
```